# When uninstalling a software, why doesn't windows remove all associated files?

Tags: windows-10

When uninstalling a software, why doesn't windows remove all associated files? (eg. regedit entries, %appdata%, and %programfiles%.)

It is quite a pain to have to do it manually. Why aren't these files and entries automatically removed along with the "main" software files if you can say so.

I mean, at least windows could give the user an option to look for these remnant files and remove them.

I am not sure whether this is the case for all windows versions. If that is not the case, I would like to know the case for windows 10.

Comment: There are times you wouldn't want this. Like if you were reinstalling a piece of software, or updating software to a different version, you wouldn't want that data/files removed.

Comment: Traditionally uninstallers have not received the attention they deserve. In many cases they are little more than an afterthought. Many developers and the companies that employ them have difficulty understanding why anyone would wish to uninstall and not use their application. So why devote a lot of time to it? From their perspective this would seem a reasonable attitude.

Answer (score 1):

For traditional .exe programs:

1. Windows does not know which entries belong to the application; even for HKCU\Software all it has is the name (which might be slightly different or even completely different).
2. Windows doesn't know which entries belong *exclusively* to the application, and aren't being shared between multiple apps.
3. Many users uninstall a program just to reinstall a different version afterwards, so removing all associated data would cause preferences and everything else to be lost.
4. The same program might be used by multiple users on the same computer, and the user uninstalling the program does not have permissions to read and write all other users' profiles. (That's not just a technical limitation – I think most people would be quite against their files getting mysteriously removed because another person uninstalled something.)

That said, most of those problems have been solved by "Microsoft Store" app packages – they're self-contained as much as possible. They are always installed per-user, and Windows creates a dedicated registry hive for each "Store" app, so whenever you uninstall the app it can simply delete the entire hive, with all registry entries ever created.

Comment: At the end of the day, the registry was designed to grow and be used, there is absolutely not hit in performance by having keys not associated with something.  Now keys that start an automatically start an application should be cleaned up but that is a different question.  In other words, there is no benefit to cleaning up file associations, if a program associated with file extension no longer exists it's a single click to associate it with another program.

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect. Notice that I didn't downvote, as courtesy between SU colleagues.

Comment: I do not play "internet point colleagues" here.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed the case for every Windows version that ever existed.

The problem here is not inherent to Windows, which actually for desktop products
only runs the uninstall program that came with the product.
It is deficiencies in the uninstall program that cause leftovers.

Some installation packages are created by a standard installer, with the additional
benefit that it automatically creates the uninstall program, so saves the
programmer the trouble of doing it himself.

Unfortunately, this uninstaller only knows how to uninstall the files and shortcuts
that it installed. It does not know about files or registry modifications that were
done by the program *after it was installed*.

To find out these later changes, a specialized program called
[uninstaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninstaller)
is used. This program will scan the file system and the registry looking for
left-over items. Items that it finds might point to more items, and so on.

Uninstallers may make mistakes by suggesting too many items.
This is why a good uninstaller will display a list of what it intends to delete
and let you unselect items. A good uninstaller can be trusted not to overdo
deletes.

You can find a list of free uninstallers with reviews in the article
[Best Free Program Uninstaller](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-program-un-installer.htm).
Using an uninstaller is always recommended for keeping the computer clean
from left-overs.